# Merge calls option shows a popup 'Conference call not allowed'

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls

While trying to make a conference call using the merge calls button, my Micromax A25 with Android2.3.6 shows a popup displaying 'Condference call not allowed'. Can you please tell me whether it is OS related or my operator related ? Or there is any settings that needs to be enabled for activating conference calling in my device?

Comment: This is generally turned off in Indian prepaid connections. Speak to the customer care to enable it. I believe you need a minimum balance to turn it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's operator-related. Although the phone can support conference calling, most consumer calling plans don't let you do that.